# Instance of one class within another class

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

I have

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract A get();
}
```

and

```
public abstract class B
{
    public abstract void save(A a);
}
```

And bunch of different classes that extend these two classes.
And they are usually paired together. So if I have classes C, D
Then **C would extend A** and **D would extend B** and D's save function would expect C in order for it to work.

And I have controller E

```
public class E
{
    List<B> list;

    public void save(A a)
    {
        // how do I choose correct pair from list?
    }
}
```

In that controller I have a list of classes that extend B.
There is a save function in E that receives extended class A as an argument.
How do I loop through all the elements in the list and figure out which class belongs to which in the pair?

Thanks to anyone for their help, I am trying to learn complex abstract classes and how to relate them.

**EDIT**: If I use instance of then I will have a huge if statements inside 100 classes

Let's say I have 100 classes that extend class A and 100 that extend class B.
They are paired together as I explained above.

So as a further clarification.

```
public class D extends B
{
    public void save(A a)
    {
        C c = (C)a.get();
        // proceed saving using c
    }
}
```

How do I avoid doing a check for instance of inside all these classes, and know how to pair them? Is there no better way?

**EDIT2**: Pshemo answer is great, however I have one last question to solve.

In class E I have save function that receives class A
How do I know which class that A is linked to?
If class A is instance of C how would I know to search for instance of D in the list and call that classes' save function?

Comment: Quick dirty way: use `instanceof`. Proper way: do not use inheritance for this.

Comment: I'm unsure about your design. Anyway, perhaps trying to cast and see if your instance is castable to your expected type will tell you which type it is.

Comment: I think you need to clarify this somewhat.  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "figure out which class belongs to which in the pair".  I think you should add some code that demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish, and just make something up for the parts where you don't know how to write correct Java code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Brilliant! Didn't think of it directly, though my thought revolves around the same.

Comment: Yes, `instanceof` of will work fine -- you can check if the classes are instances of either the parent classes or the child classes. You could also catch a `ClassCastException` if you'd prefer the exception-handling route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you need, but it looks like you may want to change `B` class to something like

```
abstract class B<T extends A> {
    public abstract void save(T a);
}
```

so now when you extend it you can specify which class should `T` represent, like

```
class D extends B<C> {
    public void save(C a) {}
}
```

Comment: This is excellent :) one more question. In class E when I am looping through all the instances of class B, how do I figure out this link? So if class E's save function receives class C, how do I figure out that I need to call instance of class D's save function and not some other class' save function?

Comment: @Quillion Sorry for late response, I needed to go AFK. There are few strategies, and each of them has its pros and cons. For instance instead of List, you could use `Map<Class<?>, B>` which will store instances of `B` like `D1`, `D2, `D3` or others and in `save(A a)` you could use something like `map.get(a.getClass()).save(a)`.

Comment: @Quillion Other approach could be storing informations about which extension of `B` should be used in `C`. You can do it by many ways (1) store class literal (instance of Class), (2) or maybe make classes extending B singletons and in `C` add method which will return instance of this implementation.

Comment: I used maps along with the thing you showed, and it worked wonderfully :) Thank you so much, this was an extremely fun learning experience

Comment: @Quillion I am glad you liked it :)